# AngularJs Multiple Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on multiple directive, this is already existing framework so I dont want to disturb the existing components.

This is my HTML

```
<div title="test" mydirective>
```

This is my directive, this has templateUrl with it and this template has another directive getting loaded.

```
.directive('myDirective', function ($filter) {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
            title: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'partial/partialtemplate.tpl.html'
});
```

My Partial Template html looks like this

```
<div newdirective title="{{title}}"></div>
```

This is my newdirective

```
.directive('newDirective', function ($filter) {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
            title: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'partial/newpartialtemplate.tpl.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
        //here if I try to print my title I still get {{title}}
        console.log($attrs.title);
    }
});
```

So what could the issue be, I the second directive being called even before the template data is written or anything wrong?

Comment: I think you forget to write your html partial code. Show here what have you done in that

Comment: There you go, you can see that now. I had not indented properly.

Comment: You need to use $observe while retrieving title. Its interpolation issue.

Comment: $attrs.$observe('title', function() {
         console.log($attrs.title);
});
This is throwing error.

Comment: actually would be cleaner to handle all attr dependent code in the link function. at that point all DOM has been compiled and is ready to link